# Creating chart with filled gap between lines

Tags: python, pandas, web, charts

I'm trying to create a chart like shown in the image. I've created this in excel, but I'd like to include it in a real-time web dashboard.

The chart contains two separate data streams (stream1 and stream2). I need to create a chart which will paint in green all areas were stream1 has value greater than stream 2, and red when it's lower.

I have the timseries as dataframes in pandas, python.

Could anyone suggest the best/easiest way I could create such a chart?

Thank you.

[image: Chart I'm hoping to achieve.]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any libraries in particular?

Comment: Have a look at [this Matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html)

Comment: I have my graphs using google charts so far. But I'm not sure that's the best way to create this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nils gave you correct answer to check [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html)

#### Dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

series1 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(20))
series2 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(20)+0.3)
```

#### Plot

```
plt.fill_between(series1.index, series1, series2, where=series2>=series1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5, interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(series1.index, series2, series1, where=series2<=series1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, interpolate=True)
```

[image]